# Categorical Classification probabilites as a graph

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, pytorch, networkx

What is the best way to take the categorical classification probabilities typically output from a neural network and plot them as a graph using something like `networkx`.

Given 8 categories, say `['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H']` and the predictions across 5 samples with shape `(8, 5)` I'd like to plot a graph where the node label is the category and the probability for all indices where the probability is greater than 0.0.

```
array([[0.        , 0.        , 0.        , 0.        , 0.        ],
       [0.        , 0.        , 0.        , 0.        , 0.        ],
       [0.17817138, 0.11233618, 0.12554741, 0.16154018, 0.16248149],
       [0.        , 0.        , 0.        , 0.        , 0.        ],
       [0.70687366, 0.86215913, 0.85997397, 0.8285762 , 0.828603  ],
       [0.        , 0.        , 0.        , 0.        , 0.        ],
       [0.        , 0.        , 0.        , 0.        , 0.        ],
       [0.        , 0.        , 0.        , 0.        , 0.        ]],
      dtype=float32)
```

Valid edges are between all the non zero values of consecutive columns in the array.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you want a graph in which vertices represent classes and edges represent two classes having non-zero probability for the same data instance.

Starting with data similar to yours (since yours has only 2 classes ever having non-zero proability)...

```
import numpy as np

A = np.array([[0.        , 0.        , 0.        , 0.8285762 , 0.        ],
              [0.        , 0.        , 0.        , 0.        , 0.        ],
              [0.17817138, 0.        , 0.12554741, 0.        , 0.16248149],
              [0.        , 0.        , 0.        , 0.10000000, 0.        ],
              [0.70687366, 0.        , 0.85997397, 0.06154018, 0.828603  ],
              [0.        , 0.11233618, 0.        , 0.        , 0.        ],
              [0.11495425, 0.        , 0.        , 0.        , 0.        ],
              [0.        , 0.86215913, 0.        , 0.        , 0.        ]
             ])
```

There's probably a cunning NumPy move here, but with a loop over classes we can build an edge list:

```
from itertools import combinations

edge_list = []
idx = np.argwhere(A.T)
for i, _ in enumerate(A):
    this = idx[idx[:, 0]==i]
    combs = combinations(this[:, 1], r=2)
    edge_list.extend(list(combs))
edge_list
```

You can instantiate a `networkx.Graph` and add the edges like so:

```
import networkx as nx

G = nx.Graph()
G.add_edges_from(edge_list)
```

Then you can draw the graph with `nx.draw(G)` but th default drawing is not great. We can prepare the node size and labels...

```
nx.set_node_attributes(G, {i:chr(65+i) for i in range(len(A))}, 'name')
nx.set_node_attributes(G, {i:sum(a) for i, a in enumerate(A)}, 'prob')

probs = nx.get_node_attributes(G, 'prob')
sizes = [1000*x for x in probs.values()]
labels = nx.get_node_attributes(G, 'name')
```

Then make a better plot:

```
%matplotlib inline
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(10, 6))

pos = nx.spring_layout(G)
nx.draw_networkx_nodes(G, pos, ax=ax, node_size=sizes, node_color='orange')
nx.draw_networkx_edges(G, pos, ax=ax, width=4, splines='curved')
nx.draw_networkx_labels(G, pos,
                        labels=labels,
                        font_size=20,
                        font_family='sans-serif',
                        font_color='blue')

plt.axis('off')
plt.show()
```

[image: A plot of the resulting graph.]